# egrep "[\w]+" doesnt match a word

Tags: regex

In linux, when i try a simple egrep for a word it doesnt match. The following doesnt return any result, however i expect **sample** in both the cases to match:

```
echo "sample"|egrep "[\w]+"
echo "sample"|egrep "[\w]"
```

However the following returns the word **sample** :

```
echo "sample"|egrep "[\w]*"
sample
```

Answer (score 3):

With the **e**xtended matching, entities like `\w` are not expanded inside square brackets. Therefore avoid them:

```
echo sample | grep -E '\w+'
```

(`egrep` is a deprecated alias for `grep -E`.)

---

If you really want to use square brackets, then use **p**erl regular expressions:

```
echo sample | grep -P '[\w]+'
```

(Note though that this is a GNU-specific, non-POSIX feature.)

---

Finally, for your interest, `[\w]*` with `-E` does not match a word, but it matches zero or more characters. And given that at least zero characters are contained in every string, `grep` shows every line. Compare:

```
echo another.sample | grep --color=always -E '[\w]*'
echo another.sample | grep --color=always -E '\w+'
```

You'll see that the first command returns a black string (meaning that it has not matched any character). The second one instead will highlight *another* and *sample*, but not the dot, meaning that it has correctly matched the two words. You may also want to try with `grep -Eo`.

Comment: Thanks andrea :) Isnt it a bug that with extended matching \w doesnt work? Are there other entities too like \w which wouldnt work when inside brackets? I tried searching alot but could not get any reference to such scenario.

Comment: @anurag86: the behavior is not a bug and is described in the man page for grep: *A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed by **[** and **]**. It matches any single character in that list*. If you look, you'll see that the backslash character has no special meaning.